# Chances of being picked last in a hat

Tags: probability

A couple of friends and I are struggling with coming up with an answer to this question.  It's seemingly simple but I need a little help.

> 6 people put their name into a hat.  One by one, names are pulled
>   **without replacement**.  What are the odds that your name will be picked
>   **last**?

My thoughts are: in each pick you're looking at the odds that your name is **not** getting picked. So first it's $\frac{5}{6}$, then $\frac{4}{5}$, then $\frac{3}{4}$, $\frac{2}{3}$, $\frac{1}{2}$. And it's the chance you don't get picked first AND you don't get picked second, third ... so

$$\frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{6}$$

Agree/Disagree?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: a similar problem: [Probability: 10th ball is blue](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1775532/11206)

Comment: The answer is 1/6 by symmetry.

Answer (score 18):

Correct. The odds that your name is picked last is the same as the odds for any other person's name being picked last. So for each person, the probability is $\dfrac{1}{6}$.

Comment: That argument extends to sampling with replacement as well (what are the chances I'm the last one to have my name appear at least once).

Answer (score 8):

It is true, and your calculation is fine.  An easier way is to imagine pulling all the names and moving the first to the end.  Clearly the first is yours with probability $1/6$

Answer (score 4):

The solution can also be expressed using factorials. $6!=720$ is the total number of combinations in which the names can be drawn out of the hat. Favourable outcomes are  $5!=120$, as the first five names may be drawn in any sequence. 
The probability that your name is picked last is $$\frac {5!}{6!} = \frac 16$$

Answer (score 4):

Here's another intuitive way to think of it: The order the names are picked is a sequence. Your name is just as likely to be at the end of that sequence as at the beginning of that sequence (or anywhere else in that sequence), and the chance of yours being picked first is $\dfrac{1}{6}$, so the chance of yours being picked last is $\dfrac{1}{6}$.

Answer (score 2):

Since all you care about in this question is the last name picked, this whole scheme is just a fancy mechanism to pick that one name out of the hat.  Because that mechanism does not at any time discriminate between the names, your probability of being picked is exactly the same as anyone else's.  So the
probability is $1/6$.

Answer (score 2):

Here might be simplest way to understand the problem:

The list of people is shuffled randomly. What is the probability of your assignment to a given position? There are six positions, so 1 in 6.

The fact that the position in question *just happens to be last* fades from view.